# MySQL CASE Constructor with Having Function

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

Following is the part of my SQL statement for MySQL tables.

```
function stockSummary($where){
    $q = $this->db->query("
    select
    item_id,
    item_name,
    unit_price,
    sub_type_name,
    pg_no,

    ( SELECT @stock := sum(ifnull(qty,0)) AS qty FROM store_update_stock_details de2 
    JOIN store_update_stock st2 ON de2.update_stock_id=st2.update_stock_id 

    RIGHT JOIN store_item item2 ON de2.item=item2.item_id WHERE de2.status = 1 and 
    st2.transfer_status = 'Approved'  AND tmp.item_id = item2.item_id GROUP BY item2.item_id) as cur_stock,

    SUM(purchase) as purchase,
    SUM(issues) as issues

    FROM (
    SELECT

    item_name,
    item_id,
    unit_price,
    store_sub_type.sub_type_name,
    store_item.pg_no,

    CASE WHEN  order_status = 'purchase' THEN  qty else 0  end as purchase , 
    CASE WHEN  order_status ='issue' and transfer_status='Issued' THEN  qty else 0  end as issues , 
    CASE WHEN  store_update_stock.status != 0 and transfer_status !='Pending' and transfer_status !='Recomended' THEN  qty else 0 
    end as balance

    from store_update_stock
    join store_update_stock_details on store_update_stock.update_stock_id=store_update_stock_details.update_stock_id
    join store_item on store_update_stock_details.item=store_item.item_id
    join store_sub_type on store_sub_type.sub_type_name=store_item.item_sub_type

    where store_update_stock.status=1 and store_item.usr != 'spsso' $where    
    )tmp

    group by item_id, unit_price


    ");
        if ($q->num_rows() > 0) {
            return $q->result();

        }
    }
```

This part is correctly outs the purchase quantity, issued quantity and the balance of items. After performing transactions balance of some items may be reached to Zero (0). I do not need to show the items reached 0 balances in the output.

How can I change my query to do that (May be applied "Having function") ? Can anyone help ?

Comment: didn't you ask this before?: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59233381/mysql-available-balance-has-not-match-with-actual-balance

Comment: @ Vickel. No this is a separate function.

Comment: I guess you have qty column to store the balances. So just use WHERE qty > 0 in your query.

Comment: @ Ankit. But my complete query as edited....